# sortable table from DB

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I've made a big table in PHP from DB and customer wants to make this table sortable.

Here is an example of the table's content

```
ID
BRAND
KIND
DESCRIPTION
PRICE
```

Customer wants to sort by price, wants to select brand and kind (as drop down list for instance)

Did you know a way to doing that? Is there a table container that can do that? if not, how Can I make this?

I mainly used Twitter Bootstrap in order to design the app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if bootstrap has the capability, but the jquery plugin - dataTables has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive enhancement, and will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.It is a framework which you can adopt it to fulfill your requirements.